# Limit calculation $\frac{x^{\ln x}}{(\ln x)^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I had trouble trying to solve this problem:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{{x^{\ln x}}}{(\ln x)^{x}}\right)$$
Do any of you know the answer?

edit:
I got it from a friend and as most of you mentioned 
x>0

Comment: By $\lim_{x\to0}$, do you mean $\lim_{x\to0^+}$? Even if $x$ is restricted to $\Bbb R^+$, how do you define $(\ln x)^x$? Do you expect the function to be complex-valued?

Comment: $(\log x)^x$ is not defined for $\log x <0$.

Comment: hod badichi, lny=[ln(x)]^2 -xln(ln(x)) . Try to evaluate the limit in this form as x approaches zero.

Comment: Using wolfram alpha, I got the result: $\infty$.Heres the link I got the result:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22x%5E%28ln%28x%29%29%2Fln%28x%29%5Ex%22

Comment: This expression is defined only for $x>1$ (because of the denominator).

Comment: As others have said, this limit only makes sense in non-real complex numbers. Is this what you're looking for?